# aspx and htm files with identical code behave differently

Tags: asp.net, css

I have two pages with identical code.  One has an aspx extension, one htm.  In Firefox they display exactly the same.  In IE8, my dropdown menus appear layered beneath the content...but only on the aspx page.  There's a slight positioning discrepancy in IE8 between the two as well.  Again, identical code, and pointing to the same css and js files...how is this even possible?

http://webdev.craftonhills.edu/Admissions_and_Financial%20Aid.aspx

http://thelionscall.com/temp/menutest/

I really need to get this working in the aspx file.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but could it be the one extra empty line to the top of the document on the second link? Doesn't that make IE8 go into quirks mode or something?

Comment: The markup delivered to the browser differs.  I'm guessing that ASP.Net is "helping" by adding the form tag and the hidden field for view state.

Answer (score 4):

One of the pages has a `FORM` tag and a div with a hidden input in it that the other doesn't.

IE will render default padding/margin on a form tag, when many other browsers will not.

I suggest using a good [CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/116754/1583).

Comment: That helped some with the jumping (though it still shifts slightly, even after I removed that form tag.  I may try a different reset), but I'm still not getting the correct behavior on the dropdowns.